# Google Cloud Storage Service Account Key Management for Signed URLs

Tags: cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

### Background

I am looking to have a Cloud Storage bucket that is not publicly accessible for images. Then my plan was to sign any image URL on the website to authorize it for a short period of time (~30 seconds) when the user loads a page. This would be for an image host style site running on App Engine (standard environment).

It looks like the way to do this is to grab the private key for the service account and sign each URL with that. I had an initial hesitation embedding the key in the application since I don't understand the implications of what it can do or the best practices around it.

### Questions

1. If the service account key leaks, what can an attacker do with it?
2. What is the best way to embed it in the application? I am thinking an environment variable in `app.yaml`, that way it is not in source control but still gets deployed with the application.
3. Is there a way to bypass embedding the key since this is on App Engine? I'm building it in Golang, if there is some API that I will have access to on there. ([It looks like the V4 API will use the credentials the application is instantiated with, so this is probably the answer here.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/main/storage/objects/generate_v4_get_object_signed_url.go))
4. Any general best practices for signed URLs and Cloud Storage? For example, is there a way to use a key that only has read access to the storage bucket?

Comment: For the best answer include details on **what** your code is running on. You mention **app.yaml** which typically means App Engine (which one). For most Google Cloud services, you do not need a service account JSON key file, instead, use the metadata server or use the SDKs.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the best practice here is to use the `client.Bucket(bucket).SignedURL(object, opts)` API.

```
func storageSignUrl(object string) (string, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer client.Close()

    opts := &storage.SignedURLOptions{
        Scheme:  storage.SigningSchemeV4,
        Method:  "GET",
        Expires: time.Now().Add(15 * time.Second),
    }

    url, err := client.Bucket(bucket).SignedURL(object, opts)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return url, nil
}
```

If no key is provided, this will default to the account that AppEngine is running under. I believe you will also have to give that account the `Service Account Token Creator` role in IAM, and enable the IAM API, which should prompt you on the first visit to [this URL](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iamcredentials.googleapis.com/overview).

This avoids embedding the service account keys in source or environment variables. If you must pass secrets (e.g. the DB password) to your application, you can use the [secrets manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager). My DB password is currently in an environment variable and I have a ticket to myself to migrate it to the secrets manager.

I think this solution will work for either Standard or Flexible environment.

Comment: Small details determine what solution to deploy. Since you are using PresignedUrls, that means you need access to the service account's private key. The default credentials retrieved from the metadata server do not provide a private key for signing. That means you must use the IAM SignBlob APIs. I did not raise a fuss, I asked for details so that a correct solution can be provided.

Comment: You asked for details that were irrelevant. You didn't answer the question. You could have always answered it for both environments which would have helped people later on.